# Which framework works best for Enterprise application testing in distributed environment?

Tags: junit, continuous-integration, integration, integration-testing, jmeter

I am working in an enterprise with some legacy applications, which are quite coupled.

Integration test is thus very important. I am looking for a distributed testing framework, or a combination of them that QA team and development team can both leverage on. For "distributed" I refer to the many environments for testing, while a single application itself is not a distributed system.

The following criteria might not be the ideal model, but kind of requirement and expectation of the tool to be developed.

Such framework should be :

### **open sourced**

community support to learn, maintain and extend :)

### **distributed**

allow tests to be execute in multiple environments.
since test cases may change quite often, it should be managable to distributed those test into target machines with target codebase to run.

```
I am checking out  [STAF][1] on this.
```

### **allow integration tests**

I am looking into Camel testing. we have some existing  "simulator", "mock" to stimulate some applications behavior.
framework with easy-to-use dependency injection / mock will be very helpful..

### **with WEB UI**, wich is a single place that can

```
- all testing results are shown
- able to trigger test
- able to see testing definition
```

### **Human readable and configurable acceptance testing definition**

Testing language should be in a readable DSL
      I wonder is framework like FitNesse a good choice as I did not figure out a way to test it distributed.
     For [Citrus](http://www.citrusframework.org/)  I am concerning XML is hard to read

**Some current frameworks**

My team has been suggesting [JSystem](http://www.jsystemtest.org/), while it is possible to distribute tests, there is no web GUI and
my major concern is its development has been stopped since 2009

I looked into many frameworks as mentioned, 
[Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/#Key+features) - seems better suite web load testing?
[JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)- this seems to be closer, but also focused on load test?

**more on background:** most developers are familiar with JAVA and currently we use Hudson to run JUnit tests.

And finally I am also thinking a more conceptual issue, should xUnit test, integration test, acceptance test all being separated? xUnit test should be stick with code base? perhaps this worth another question, but with that in mind I am not sure I am looking for the right thing.

I will greatly appreciate if you can give me some comments on the thought / suggest some frameworks. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to use Jenkins Framework.

1. Open source
2. Can be used for different environments
3. I myself working over Integration Testing using Jenkins so suggest you for this.
4. Web UI is very interactive.

Large variety of plugins is available and development is still on.

Write some ANT, MAVEN scripts you can get your job done through this.